# What is the proper way to get return value from Firebase Cloud Functions onCall method in Android?

Tags: android, json

I made a function in my Cloud Functions to verify a purchase signature. It must return a boolean and a string value. I read on Firebase Cloud Functions documentation that I should return a JSON structure that contains all the values. I made it like this.

**EDIT**
This is my entire Cloud Functions:

```
const BASE_64_ENCODED_PUBLIC_KEY = "MY_PUBLIC_KEY_HERE"
const KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM = "RSA-SHA1";

// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const crypto = require('crypto');

exports.verifySignature = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const purchaseJSON = data.signedData;
    const signature = data.signature;

    console.log("start verification");

    if (purchaseJSON === null || signature === null) {
        console.log("Purchase verification failed: missing data.");
        return {
            message: "missing data",
            verified: false
        }
    }

    const verifier = crypto.createVerify(KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM);

    verifier.update(purchaseJSON);
    if (verifier.verify(publicKey, signature, "base64")){
        console.log("signature verification success!");
        return {
            message: "verification success",
            verified: true
        }
    } else {
        console.log("signature verification failed!");
        return {
            message: "verification failed",
            verified: false
        };
    }
});
```

And this is my code on the client:

```
private Task<String> verifyValidSignature(String signedData, String signature) {
    // Create the arguments to the callable function.
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("signedData", signedData);
    data.put("signature", signature);

    return mFunctions.getHttpsCallable("verifySignature")
            .call(data)
            .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
                @Override
                public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                    HttpsCallableResult result = task.getResult();
                    if (result != null) {
                        return result.getData().toString();
                    }

                    return null;
                }
            });
}
```

How can I get the `message` value and convert it to a string and the `verified` value and convert it to a boolean in Android/Java?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the **entire** Cloud Function code, and also the code you're using on the client to invoke it.

Comment: I have edited it, please take a look.

Comment: What is your client code getting as a result?  Have you examined the contents of `result.getData()`?  Is something not working the way you expect?

Comment: This is what I got from result.getData() `{verified=true, message=verification success}`. I want to get the verified value as boolean and message value as String in Java/Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`result.getData()` is returning a Map type object, because you returned an object from the function.  JavaScript objects become Java Maps.  You just use it like you would any other Map.

```
Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>) result.getData();
String message = (String) data.get("message");
boolean verified = (Boolean) data.get("verified");
```

Comment: I doubt that your first line code is a bit wrong, do you mean I need to typecast the `result.getData()` to `Map<String, Object>`? Because the above code gives me an error `Expression expected`. I tried to change it to typecast but I got a warning `Unchecked cast`. What should I do?

Comment: Yes, it's a cast, but I forgot the parenthesis.  Edited.

Comment: How about the `Unchecked cast` warning? Should I ignore it?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is ok, the only thing missing is to promosify it, this would do the trick

```
 return Promise.resolve({ message: “verification success”, verified: true })
```

Similar for the error case but instead of using Promise.resolve you will use Promise.reject

Comment: Actually, I'm asking for how to get the `message` and `verified` appropriate value in Java/Android. So, `message` will be String, while `verified` will become a boolean. Btw, am I really need to return Promise? Because I've tried to return it without Promise and I can still get the entire String.

Comment: yes, on cloud functions you need to return a promise, otherwise, the function doesn't necessarily know when to stop and can be hanging until timeout. Regarding to the other question, it seems it's not related to firebase, it is more related to the language itself